# Can I convert a View to Layout?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, view

In android, one can Inflate a `Layout` file and will get a `View` in return.
For Example:

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
View myView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.example_layout, null);
```

But I'm trying if I can get a `Layout` back from that inflated layout which is now a `View`?
Something by which I can retrieve back the original `Layout` from the Inflated `View`.

Comment: if your top most parent is a layout the your inflated view is a instance of that layout . You can downcast it to this particular layout.

Comment: @ADM can you please give some example code??

Comment: your layouts are basically View in different forms in file its layout and in java code its View so there is no question of getting layout from view because anyway you already have layout in your xml and when you need you can get it in code by View.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
LinearLayout myView = (LinearLayout)layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.example_layout, null);
```

That's it!

Just be sure that the root view in your layout.example_layout is a LinearLayout or whatever layout you desire. Otherwise you'll have a `ClassCastException`

Every layout or `ViewGroup` extends `View`, that's why the `inflate` method returns a View, it's up to you then performing the right cast.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the layout below. It has a text view only.

```
 <TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="@dimen/mediumTextSize"
    android:textColor="@color/black_text_color"
    />
```

After inflation you can directly get the textView as its the only view contain in layout.

```
 LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(this);
    TextView view=(TextView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.temp,null);
```

Now consider the layout below .

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black_text_color"
        android:textSize="@dimen/largeTExtSize" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/csvName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black_text_color"
        android:textSize="@dimen/largeTExtSize" />

</LinearLayout>
```

On inflation.

```
 LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.temp,null);
    //Or you can do
    // LinearLayout view=(LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.temp,null);
    TextView txt=view.findViewById(R.id.txtId);
```